select with more options taking whole screen
I am using the <select> where there more options. If there are more options the dropdown takes whole screen height.


select {
  max-height: 200px; /* Limit the height */
  overflow-y: auto;  /* Enable vertical scrolling */
  width: 100%;       /* Set width as needed */
}
 <select>
    <option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option><option>1</option>
 </select>



I tried to wrap the select and also give the height to the select but won't work.`
